# GWT Reset Cleared *.cache.html file

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, browser-cache

I was working on fixing a bug in my GWT+GAE application.  I kept trying to make changes and the bug persisted.  So I decided to try changing a text message in a debug statement and noticed that the text didn't change.  I assumed this was because something was being cached.  So I cleared everything I could think of (clear brower's history, rebuild the entire project, rebooted my computer, Eclipse -> Project -> Clean...).  Finally I gave up and searched for the text to see where it was hiding.  I found it in a .cache.html file so I deleted that file.  Now when I run the project, I get the following message:

[WARN] No file found for: /catserve/F0262AF37428E46FCD5FC373EED66DA6.cache.html

And the application just shows a blank webpage even after trying everything I can think of to clear the project before and after deleting the file.

How do I reset everything?

Thanks.

Comment: Since no one has responded and I can't just sit here doing nothing, the only solution I can see is to wipe out the entire project and recreate a new one, starting over with my project.  This is a ridiculous solution, but the only one I can think of to try.

Comment: Restarted a new project, but couldn't seem to use the same name.  No idea why, even though I wiped out the entire folder.  A new project with a new name seems to clear the problem.  This makes me think GWT/GAE/Eclipse is not a stable combo.

Comment: I'm facing a very similar issue right now.  I've deployed my war directory to a web server, and when I load the main page it is just a blank white screen.  I use the Chrome "Inspect Element" feature to poke around and discover that it's giving me a 404 not found error for a .cache.html file that doesn't exist.  I tried grepping in the war directory and nobody references this file!  Did you ever encounter this again and (hopefully) figure it out?

Comment: Further info: I verified that app.nocache.js script seen in the browser is out of sync (old) compared to the one on the web server. I just cleared the cache "to the beginning of time" in Chrome, and it continues to have the same problem!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Simple text changes weren't being reflected in the browser, even after a complete reboot.

To solve the issue, "GWT Compile Project..." directly, via the Google menu (in the toolbar).

I thought that Hosted Mode would address this issue, but it appears that things can get out of sync from time to time. After compiling directly, things began working again -- simple changes could be seen in the browser after saving the code, waiting for the auto-compile, and reloading the page.

Answer (score 1):

I know one thing for sure i.e. every time you change the code, `xyz.cache.html` name changes as `xyz` is "MD5 generated code". So, once you change the source code and look for the same file, it will not be there as GWT compiler had already created new `.cache.html` file with new MD5 code as file name.